# Input losing focus on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, input, focus

I'm encountering a problem on input focus, on android devices.

I've made an off-canvas menu for mobile device. In this menu i've got a search input.

The problem is, on android when I tap on the input, it focus, then the keyboard appear, then the input loses focus and keyboard disapear.

I read that i maybe have to change windowSoftInputMode in manifest's  element. But I'haven't access to this...

Do you know if it's possible to correct this in another way ??

Many thanks, sorry for my english :)

X.