# Input losing focus on sending AJAX request

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ajax

I am making a music application for Android using Intel XDK (HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and PHP), and I'm working on a fuzzy search filter, where the user types, then I filter through the music DB to display (depending on what they searched) the closest match. I've got that all working, but what isn't working (as intended) is the actual typing. What I mean is, when I type on the Android device keyboard, it disappears for some reason, sometimes after 1 key is pressed sometimes when more. I've read up on a few things which haven't provided me with a proper solotion as of yet, therefore I have created this question. Some said that because the view port is being refreshed that the input is being made unfocused as it tabs to the next element. Another link said it was because the search bar was placed underneath an element which had been positioned to be absolute.

**What have I tried? (and did not work)**

- I tried to (once the AJAX is complete) focusing the input once again.
- Tried to remove anything which might cause the view port to change while the user is typing.
- Tried changing the tab index of  other elements to -1 or 500 to make sure they can't be tabbed on to.
- Tried to remove the search bar from within another absolute positioned DIV.

**Filter JS Code (POST Request)**

```
function filter(val) {
    $.post(
        "url", {
            "query": val
        }, function (data) {
            getElement("musicDiv").innerHTML = data;
        });
}
```

**HTML Input (Search Bar)**

```
<input type="search" id="searchBar" placeholder="Type to Search" title="Type to Search" onkeyup="filter(this.value);" />
```

I have nearly completed the full application, I am just struggling with this search issue and would appreciate it if someone could explain what exactly is going wrong and how to fix it.

**If CSS is required then please request it.**

Below are some of the questions I read, I'm missing another two links as I forgot the questions exact link. But the below are the closest to my issue but don't have a proper resolving answer.

[StackOverFlow Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225103/input-losing-focus-on-android-devices)

[StackOverFlow Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806697/input-losing-focus-on-dynamic-content-on-htc-android)

Comment: Side note: oninput is probably a better choice for events

Comment: @TRGWII as far as I am aware (and from what I've tried) there doesn't seem to be any compatibility issues.

Comment: I know this might seem silly, but your HTML input isn't inside the `musicDiv` element is it?

Comment: Nope, it's in a another DIV which has fixed positioning. Why? Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: @Script47 yeah, but keydown, keypress, and keyup are generally for detecting keyboard presses, but the input event detects changes to that exact field. What if someone uses a device without a keyboard, or some other weird stuff.

Comment: You make a valid point. I'll update the my code.